# How to display the names of entities from an OData model in a <List> component SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, entity, sapui5

I would like to display the names of the entities in an OData model.

I am currently using:
`var oModel = this.getView.getModel();`
To access the model from the view in the controller.

I wan to use these entity names to display them as StandardListItems in a SplitAPP.

How could I either use JavaScript or manipulate the `<List></List>` component to display the names of these entities in a list and not their properties?

Comment: Hi Keagansed, what do you mean by "Entities"? Do you want to display the name of all the possible OData Sets or all the records of one set?

Comment: I would like to display the names of the sets. So for example you would add /EntityName to display all properties of that particular entity. I would like to get all of the names of these instead of their individual properties

Comment: I think that this blog post could help you: https://blogs.sap.com/2019/01/08/a-general-ui5-application-for-reviewing-all-sets-inside-an-odata-service

Comment: Also this one: https://openui5.blogspot.com/2017/12/odata-explorer.html